# Invoke API in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, api, t-sql

I would like to invoke an API from SQL Server, below is the curl script for that. Is it possible to invoke the API and get response from SQL Server?

```
curl -k -X POST https://xxx.xxxxx.co.za:8442/rest/Session/login -d params='{"login":"usrname","password":"password"}'
```

Comment: That would be a very bad idea. Same for every database product. You can code it, but it's still a very bad idea. Why do you think you want this? Why make the call from inside the database instead of ... just make that `curl` call in a script and store the results in the database? Or write a small program that makes the call, parses the response and writes the parsed results?

Comment: This is a bad idea because HTTP calls are extremely slow, which means a server thread is tied up waiting for a response. During that time, any locks acquired before the HTTP call remain active, blocking other queries. Besides, a single HTTP call is never enough. After logging in you'll want to actually do something with that site, keeping cookies, state *and* locks from one call to the other. Your code will end up locking rows for a long time. Besides, T-SQL is really bad at general purpose programming. It would be a lot easier to use another language

Comment: For example, you can write a PowerShell script to run `Invoke-RestMethod`, parse the results and use `Write-SqlTableData` to write the results to a table. You can use any .NET class in a PowerShell script. You can also call `curl` or any other application in the script. If you use PowerShell Core, your script will run on Windows, Linux, MacOS without modifications